# cloud froundry No org found (cf target -o ORG -s SPACE)

Tags: ruby, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have installed local cloud foundry version using bosh lite. When I login using bosh login  i dont see any organization. It shows me a prompt and asks me  to enter email and password. 
 I want to create an org

```
$:~/cf-release$ ./cf login
API endpoint: https://api.bosh-lite.com
Email> admin
Password>
Authenticating...
OK
API endpoint:   https://api.bosh-lite.com (API version: 2.43.0)
User:           admin
No org or space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE'
```

When I do cf orgs it doesnt show me any org and message "No orgs found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cf help create-org** should get you started.